# Java BorderLayout: JComponents set to EAST and WEST appear outside of JFrame

Tags: java

I have class BoardView that extends `JFrame` that uses `BorderLayout` and the `CENTER` field of that layout is a class BoardPanel that extends `JPanel` and uses `BorderLayout` also. The `CENTER` field of this `JPanel` uses `GridLayout`.

Here is my code for BoardPanel:

```
public class BoardPanel extends JPanel {
  private ArrayList<Pit> pits;
  private JPanel pitGrid;

  public BoardPanel() {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    pitGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 6));
    pits = new ArrayList<Pit>();
  }

  public void initializeBoard(StyleStrategy s) {
    Pit mancalaA = new Pit(s, true);
    Pit mancalaB = new Pit(s, true);
    this.add(mancalaA, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.add(mancalaB, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.add(pitGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    for (int i=0; i < 12; i++) {
      Pit pit = new Pit(s, false);
      pitGrid.add(pit);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I set the `EAST` and `WEST` fields of BoardPanel to a `JComponent`, those components appear just outside of the `JFrame`:
[image]

You can see in the image above the 2-by-6 `GridLayout`, but the two red blocks in the EAST and WEST areas are not visible.

I searched around and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122838/how-do-i-stop-center-of-borderlayout-from-taking-up-east-and-west) that I thought was related to my problem. I added two `Box` rigid areas at the EAST and WEST locations of the outermost BorderLayout and got this as a result:
[image]

So now there are spacers on both sides of the CENTER area of the outermost BorderLayout, but those two red blocks still appear *outside* of those spacers.

I tried substituting BoardPanel's `BorderLayout` for a 1-by-3 `GridLayout` and I kinda got a little bit closer to what I expect:
[image]

But now each column is the same size which is unacceptable. It seems that a work around would be to use `GridBagLayout`, but that seems really complicated and most of the solutions to the problem of wanting to resize columns in `GridLayout` are just to use `BorderLayout` instead.

Here is the Pit class code:

```
public class Pit extends JComponent {
  StyleStrategy style;
  boolean isMancala;

  public Pit(StyleStrategy s, boolean m) {
    style = s;
    isMancala = m;
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(style.getColor());
    Shape pit;
    if (isMancala)
      pit = style.createMancala();
    else
      pit = style.createPit();
    g2.fill(pit);
    g2.draw(pit);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think they are actually outside the visible area. It's more likely that they are 0 pixels wide, due to the way various sizing methods work. You can verify this by checking `mancalaA.getWidth()` and `mancalaB.getWidth()` after the GUI is visible.

Comment: Indeed, `mancala*.getWidth()` returns 0 -- by why is it that when I use `GridLayout` instead, I can see them (obviously they are wider than 0) but `mancala*.getWidth()` still returns 0?

Comment: GridLayout forces all components to the size of the largest child.  What is returned by the getPreferredSize method of the Pit class?

Comment: `java.awt.Dimension[width=0,height=0]`

Comment: That's a good question which I don't know the exact answer to off-hand. Are you sure you're checking the size after the components are made visible? That might also happen if you aren't calling `pack()` on the `JFrame`.

Comment: @VGR I added code for the Pit class. It's responsible for drawing `Shape` (`Rectangle2D.Double`) objects that have their dimensions defined in another class. I'm not sure how to force a particular size for those shapes...

Comment: @Radiodef I tried calling `pack()` in my BoardView class after the BoardPanel is made and added to the BorderLayout, but all that does is make the JFrame really skinny like this:
http://imgur.com/a/d3pOX

and when I resize the JFrame it looks the same as before.

Comment: Since Pit doesn’t define a preferred size, its preferred size is 0×0, which is why it takes up no space in your BorderLayout.  Override the `getPreferredSize` method to return nonzero dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @VGR, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to VGR for providing the answer which was to override `getPreferredSize()` in the Pit class.